# GROUP BY twice and SUM

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table with data like this

```
code | month | sales | value
1    |  1    | 1     |  4
1    |  1    | 2     |  2
1    |  2    | 1     |  2
2    |  1    | 1     |  4
```

and I want to group the data like this

```
code | month | sales | value
1    |   1   |  1    |  6
1    |   1   |  2    |  2
2    |   1   |  1    |  4
```

so far I have this mysql query

```
SELECT code,month,sales,sum(value) as value FROM data GROUP BY code
```

but it only gives this result

```
code | month | sales | value
1    |   1   |  1    |  8
2    |   1   |  1    |  4
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: `group by code,sales`

Comment: Did you try to add sales also to GROUP BY?

Answer (score 5):

These will give u expected result:

```
SELECT code,month,sales,sum(value) as value FROM data GROUP BY code, sales
```